# Deleting object array with for loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am having trouble with figuring out how to delete array of objects in my homework.

Declaration looks like this:

```
Sprite*     gCharacter[64] ;
```

And then in WndProc function.

```
case WM_DESTROY:
        for(int i = 0; i < 64;i++){
            delete gCharacter[i];
        }
        delete gBackground;
        delete gBackBuffer;
        DeleteDC(ghSpriteDC);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
```

With this for loop I get assertion error like if I would try something like this:

```
delete gCharacter[0];
delete gCharacter[0];
```

I can't figure out why is that happening and how to delete this array properly. If nothing I will just manually type out: `delete gCharacter[from 0 to 63]` but that would look pretty messy.

This fixed

```
for(int i = 0; i < 180; i++){
            gCharacter[i] = 0;
            delete gCharacter[i];
        }
```

this error: `_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)`
but I have no idea why do I have to set NULL value first.

Comment: Can you explain how this array is being populated? Are all of the objects unique?

Comment: Please post the assertion error, as well as the declarations for `gBackground`, `gBackBuffer` and other variables you haven't declared.  As well, know that you can't delete the same section of memory twice from the same allocation.  Also (I know, a lot of cases), how was gCharacter allocated?  Did they use `new` or `malloc`?  This is obviously Win32, and some of the built-ins use the old C function, which is not freed the same way as operator `new`.

Comment: Make sure that at each array index you have a valid Sprite pointer. Also make sure they are distinct. ex. initialization for(int i=0;i<64;++i) gCharacter[i]=new Sprite(...);

Comment: Ensure that the array elements are initialised to `NULL` in case all elements are not used: `Sprite* gCharacter[64] = {};`

Comment: `case WM_DESTROY` called two times?

Comment: Is upvoting question of kind "Here are few lines of my program. It fails. Guess what's the error message and what's in code I didn't put here" a part of some promotion to gain new users?

Comment: The posted edit introduces a memory leak and goes beyond the end of the array: `i < 180` but only 64 elements.

Comment: You fixed nothing with your change. Now `delete` is no-op because you throw away pointer that you previously deleted and repeatedly try to delete NULL pointer. So you got rid of (probable) double deleting by no deleting at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the limited code you posted, there are 2 obvious cases where you would get an assertion in your loop :

1) One (or more) of your 64 pointers have not been properly initialized. If you don't initialize your pointers to `NULL` at first, and do not call `new` for each and every one of them without exception, one of those 64 deletes will fail because it will try to free memory that has not been allocated (deleting a `NULL` pointer is valid and does nothing, but does not assert)

2) Some of your 64 pointers point to the same `Sprite` instance. In that case, when the first one gets deleted, the second pointer still points at the same memory address, which has already been deallocated (and maybe even reallocated for a different purpose in the meantime). This second delete on the same memory address will fail with a double-free assertion.

There are obviously other situations where you could get an assertion, but you didn't post enough code to debug thoroughly, and the 2 I listed are the most common ones.